# Magento 2 - Hide/Show custom EAV attribute after if condition

Tags: magento2, eav, eav-attributes

I created a new EAV attribute using this code :

```
'information',
    [
        'group' => 'Content',
        'type' => 'int',
        'default' => null,
        'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
        'visible' => false
    ]
```

**PS: I added this attribute to the product form**

this attribute is by default hidden, but I want to visible it after a condition, is there any method to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do that using a plugin. Try following way to doing this. Following example will hide product name. For your custom attribute you need to modify plugin code.

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\General">
        <plugin name="sr_attribute_visibility"
                type="SR\MagentoCommunity\Plugin\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\General" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/SR/MagentoCommunity/Plugin/Catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/General.php

```
<?php
namespace SR\MagentoCommunity\Plugin\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;


class General
{
    public function afterModifyMeta(
        \Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\General $subject,
        $meta
    ) {
        // add your condition
        $meta['product-details']['children']['container_name']['children']['name']['arguments']['data']['config']['visible'] = 0;
        // print $meta and check your custom attribute index.
        return $meta;
    }
}
```

**[Update]**

Suppose **information** is text attribute. Now modify following way:

```
<?php
namespace SR\MagentoCommunity\Plugin\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;


class General
{
    public function afterModifyMeta(
        \Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\General $subject,
        $meta
    ) {
        // add your condition
        if (isset($meta['product-details']['children']['container_information'])) {
            $meta['product-details']['children']['container_information']['children']['information']['arguments']['data']['config']['visible'] = 0;
        }

        return $meta;
    }
}
```

**PS: the attribute visibility should be by default: true (false don't work)**

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir, That I need to change this `['name']` with `['information']` ? name of my EAV attribute

Comment: I think you need to change container_name too. In your case should container_information.

Comment: I get this error `The "componentType" configuration parameter is required for the "container_information" component`

Comment: Try using: $meta['product-details']['children']['container_information']['children']['information']['arguments']['data']['config']['visible'] = 0;

Comment: Check updated answer

Comment: still the same error, I think the problem is on the default configuration of the attribute because I didn't give it the `group` ... etc, or that has no inconvenience?

Comment: I created new attribute from admin and assign under product details. So you need to do that. Also I have updated answer, now error never throw.

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir, and I'm sorry for being late to respond. The code still not working, I can't hide/show the input from the form, if it's work for you please share with me the configuration of EAV attribute, and you can see the new update for my post

Comment: When I try the code for an exiting input like `sku` for example it's work, but for the EAV attribute no

Comment: Show how you created attribute.

Comment: I created a new attribute from admin and assign this to attribute set under product details group.

Comment: I found the error on `group` when I make it on Content it's doesn't work, and now it's work perfectly sir, Thanks a lot for your help sir and really sorry for the inconvenience